# how to get time when a link to the product has been created. Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I have a some product. I want to add a link of this product in different category, but i need to known when a link was created.

I have a collection of links(***CurrentDocument.Links***) of this product, but i need to known time when some link was created.

How to get difference of links if I get these links with help *CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode CurrentDocument.Links*

Answer (score 1):

Would you please provide more information regarding your problem. Some code would be great.

However, if you are getting links with *TreeNode* help you can use *DocumentCreatedWhen* property to get the date and time when the document was created.